# Relative directory loading in routing.yml without bundle reference

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm trying to use Symfony2 without bundles. When my routing.yml looks like this:

```
app:
    resource: "/var/www/oo_talks/src/UI"
    type:     annotation
```

Everything works in browser. But how do I get rid of full path here if I do not use bundles? How can I reference root project folder?

And still, running console command gives error about being unable to load a resource.

Added later, based on comments:

- `resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/src/UI"` doesn't work as well as `resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/UI"`. Still "Cannot load resource" error.
- Adding parameter with full path and referencing it doesn't work either.

Comment: Shooting from the hip here - have you tried `resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/src/UI"`?

Comment: you don't have a src/ folder or content in this directory project ?

Comment: @JasonRoman Doesn't work. BTW, it should be `resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/UI"` because `%kernel.root_dir%` points to `app` folder of the project. My `src is at the project root`.

Comment: @darkomen I do. With full path passed it works.

Comment: What about just adding a global parameter for your root directory so you just have to define it once and then you can reuse it everywhere else

Comment: @JasonRoman How do I do that? Do you mean parameter like `%kernel.root_dir%`? BTW, if `%kernel.root_dir%` doesn't work, how that new parameter will do?

Comment: In `parameters.yml.dist` you could add a parameter called `app.root_dir: "/var/www/oo_talks"` or whatever you want to name that, then in your routing config you'd put `resource: "%app.root_dir%/UI"`

Comment: @JasonRoman Doesn't work. Just like `%kernel.root_dir%`.

Comment: oops i meant `app.root_dir: "/var/www/oo_talks/src"`

Comment: @JasonRoman Parameters there seem not to parse. Doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101333/discussion-between-jason-roman-and-vladislav-rastrusny).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default relative path is resolved by `file_locator` service relatively to the `%kernel.root_dir%/Resources` directory or relatively to the directory of the file where path was specified.

Comment: How do you specify relative path to resoure? `resource: "../../src/AppBundle/Controller/"` instead of `resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"` works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I dropped that branch of code and moved to a single-bundle config, cannot check now.